# What is the verb that describes the situation where you pretend you forgot something?

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb that describes the situation where someone tries to fake forgetting .. pretending he forgot something but he didn't?

I wish you get my point.

Comment: it's called lying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no word for pretending to forget, but there is the verb *to feign*.  One could *feign forgetfulness*.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that:

> - He kicked the problem in the long grass *(= He reacted to the problem by doing something to make sure that everyone would forget about it instead of trying to solve it)*
> - His forgetfulness is *make-believe*.
> - He faked having forgotten.
> - He feigned having forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way of saying this is contained in the question - he pretended to forget.....